# All combination of values in given columns and sum of another column based on that

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data as below in the python pandas data frame. Is there any way I can get the output as below?. Right now I need to get the desired data in an iterative manner. The expected output of other similar posts looks different.

```
col1 col2 col3 Col4
A1   B1   C1   10
A2   B2   C2   20
A3   B3   C3   30
```

Sample Output. Not all combinations are listed here. But to give an idea

```
col1 col2 col3 Col4
A1             sum       
A2             sum     
A3             sum
A1   B1        sum
A1   B2        sum
A1        C1   sum
A2        C2   sum
     B1   C1   sum
     B2   C2   sum  
A1   B1   C1   sum
A1   B1   C2   sum
```

Comment: Are you using pandas or just printing to console?

Comment: @sjd how is sum calculated?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi It is a simple of `sum(Col4)` based on the cols. For eg. First row sum is sum(Col4) of all "Col1==A1" rows

Answer (score 0):

This is not compact version but the result is fine:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data = StringIO("""
col1   col2   col3   Col4
A1   B1   C1   10
A2   B2   C2   20
A3   B3   C3   30
""")

# load data into data frame
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='   ', engine='python')

# get unique values from each column
a = list(df['col1'].values)
b = list(df['col2'].values)
c = list(df['col3'].values)


def get_value(string):
    value = int(list(string)[1]) * 10
    return value


# generate dictionary combinations
data = {}
# for single item
for item in a:
    data.setdefault('col1', []).append(item)
    data.setdefault('col2', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col3', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col4', []).append(get_value(item))

for item in b:
    data.setdefault('col1', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col2', []).append(item)
    data.setdefault('col3', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col4', []).append(get_value(item))

for item in c:
    data.setdefault('col1', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col2', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col3', []).append(item)
    data.setdefault('col4', []).append(get_value(item))

# for double items
xy = [(x,y) for x in a for y in b]
xz = [(x,z) for x in a for z in c]
yz = [(y,z) for y in b for z in c]

for item in xy:
    data.setdefault('col1', []).append(item[0])
    data.setdefault('col2', []).append(item[1])
    data.setdefault('col3', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col4', []).append(get_value(item[0])+get_value(item[1]))

for item in xz:
    data.setdefault('col1', []).append(item[0])
    data.setdefault('col2', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col3', []).append(item[1])
    data.setdefault('col4', []).append(get_value(item[0])+get_value(item[1]))

for item in yz:
    data.setdefault('col1', []).append('')
    data.setdefault('col2', []).append(item[0])
    data.setdefault('col3', []).append(item[1])
    data.setdefault('col4', []).append(get_value(item[0])+get_value(item[1]))


# for triple items
xyz = [(x,y,z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]

for item in xyz:
    data.setdefault('col1', []).append(item[0])
    data.setdefault('col2', []).append(item[1])
    data.setdefault('col3', []).append(item[2])
    data.setdefault('col4', []).append(get_value(item[0]) + get_value(item[1]) + get_value(item[2]))

# load into df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3  col4
0    A1              10
1    A2              20
2    A3              30
3         B1         10
4         B2         20
5         B3         30
6              C1    10
7              C2    20
8              C3    30
9    A1   B1         20
10   A1   B2         30
11   A1   B3         40
12   A2   B1         30
13   A2   B2         40
14   A2   B3         50
15   A3   B1         40
16   A3   B2         50
17   A3   B3         60
18   A1        C1    20
19   A1        C2    30
20   A1        C3    40
21   A2        C1    30
22   A2        C2    40
23   A2        C3    50
24   A3        C1    40
25   A3        C2    50
26   A3        C3    60
27        B1   C1    20
28        B1   C2    30
29        B1   C3    40
30        B2   C1    30
31        B2   C2    40
32        B2   C3    50
33        B3   C1    40
34        B3   C2    50
35        B3   C3    60
36   A1   B1   C1    30
37   A1   B1   C2    40
38   A1   B1   C3    50
39   A1   B2   C1    40
40   A1   B2   C2    50
41   A1   B2   C3    60
42   A1   B3   C1    50
43   A1   B3   C2    60
44   A1   B3   C3    70
45   A2   B1   C1    40
46   A2   B1   C2    50
47   A2   B1   C3    60
48   A2   B2   C1    50
49   A2   B2   C2    60
50   A2   B2   C3    70
51   A2   B3   C1    60
52   A2   B3   C2    70
53   A2   B3   C3    80
54   A3   B1   C1    50
55   A3   B1   C2    60
56   A3   B1   C3    70
57   A3   B2   C1    60
58   A3   B2   C2    70
59   A3   B2   C3    80
60   A3   B3   C1    70
61   A3   B3   C2    80
62   A3   B3   C3    90
```

Comment: Yeah... I could do the iteration something similar method. But I was looking for any inbuilt function or package which can do the job

Comment: @sjd try to use `itertools import combinations`